# Attempting to insert into mongodb through javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongodb, node and the like, I was trying to perform a simple task of inserting a blogpost into my database that I already created, what I decided to do is to make a web page with a button, once clicked, would then insert into my mongo database, but unfortunately I've been failing to do so. I know to insert I must use the terminal, for example node server.js and then it'll insert, however I want that to occur by just pressing the button on the html page. So any advice on what to do will be appreciated, the following is my current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
Add Blog Post
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Welcome to your Blog! Feel free to add a blog post!
</h1>
<form>
Title: <br>
<input type = "text" name = "Title" id = "title"><br>
Blog Post: <br>
<input type = "text" name ="EnterBlog" id = "blog"> <br>

<input type = "button" value = "Submit Blog" onclick="
var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
 var collection = db.collection('blog');
 var title = Title.value;
 var blog = EnterBlog.value;
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {Title: title}, {Blog : blog}
  ], function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    assert.equal(2, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(2, result.ops.length);
    console.log('Inserted 2 documents into the Blog collection');
    callback(result);
  });
}
exports.insertDocuments = insertDocuments;

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/blogapp';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log('Connected correctly to server');

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    db.close();
  });
});"
>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NodeJS is server side technology not client side. It doesn't run inside client browser. I'd suggest you just do some research and do some tutorial.

Comment: Can you atleast point me in the right direction? I just want to know how I can let the user input some data and said data be stored on the database.  @Saleem

Comment: Well, google it. you'll find a lot of good tutorials including youtube videos. see http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/.